# Cannot register MAAS with Landscape after openstack-install

Tags: maas, openstack, landscape

Currently I have completed my installation of Openstack using MAAS and Lanscape. After completing the openstack-install script I am able to access the Landscape openstack web gui. Issue I am currently seeing is that the Checklist on the bottom has no items checked, first one being "Registered a MAAS region controller". When I select this entry and select register it, enter the correct IP and the MAAS API key correctly and hit save, nothing happens. If theres any logs I should be looking at or anything else anyone can point me towards that would be helpful.

Comment: I have been having the same problem with this tool. The biggest sticking point is that it has to find all of the requirements met. One that I found is that in your landscape deployment there needs to be three machines with dual NIC's.. The MAAS server needs two, NUETRON needs two and I think a third that will handle VM's. The VM's will talk on the private network, though still need access to the internet for updates, etc. (or so how I have come to work with it)

Answer (score 1):

If nothing happens after you fill in the MAAS registration form, then most likely Landscape isn't able to reach the address you provided.

The MAAS address has to be of the form `http://<hostname-or-ip>/MAAS/`. If that's what you are using, and if the hostname (or ip) is reachable from the Landscape machine, then inspecting the logs is a good idea. The most interesting log for this case would be the `job-handler.log` one, in `/var/log/landscape-logs` on the Landscape server node, or `landscape-server/0` unit if you used juju to deploy Landscape.